# How to sort n strings with length of t in Omega(nt+nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

You can access each character in `O(1)`.
And you can only ask to compare two characters which results 1,-1,0.
Meaning, `a<b, a>b, a=b`.

Obviously, sorting an array is bounded by `Omega(nlogn)`. Since for two strings we need to compare in the worst case t characters shouldn't it be `Omega(t*nlogn)`?

Comment: Yes. Sorting two strings (using comparisons sorting) is `Omega(|S| * nlogn)`, because it requires Omega(|S|) worst case comparator, and using Omega(nlogn) invokations of those.

Comment: However, if you can assume you have a finite set of alphabet, it is easy to sort in `O(n*|S| * k)`, where `k` is the alphabet size, using modifications of radix sort,  or `O(n*|S|)` if you regard `k` as constant.

Comment: Actually in section (a) of the question, the set of alphabet was `4` characters, so Radix sort was the ideal option. In section (b) the alphabet is said to be "very large".

Comment: So basically, under these terms... `Omega(nt+nlogn)` is impossible. right?

Comment: @AlonAlon It sure is impossible

Comment: Are you sure you are asking for omega and not big-O?

Comment: @user1990169, yeah. I was asked to give a lower bound.

Comment: It's not impossible.

Answer (score 3):

It's a mistake to think you need to compare every character of pairs of strings to sort the list (because if strings differ in one place, you don't need to compare them in later places). The only trick is figuring out how to do this efficiently. Here's one way.

First, build an unordered trie in O(nt) (that is, each node stores a hashtable of children, rather than a list).

There can't be more than n nodes with more than 1 immediate child, and the total number of children in these nodes can't be more than 2n (for each child above 1 adds at least one string to the trie). Therefore, sorting all immediate children of all the nodes is at worst O(n log n) (because if there's k_1, k_2, ..., k_m with sum(k_i) = 2n, then sum(k_i log k_i) <= 2n log(2n).

Once you've sorted each node, you can iterate over the trie and construct a sorted list of the strings in time O(nt).

Comment: Sorry, now I see the point of your answer. Seems good. The only problem is to assume an \Omega(1) hash table, this is only possible with perfect hashing.

Comment: @JuanLopes What if we use some balanced tree (e.g. `std::map` in C++) to store children in each node? Than it seems the cost of adding a string to a trie would be omega(k + log n), and the cost of building the trie omega(nk + n log n). In the extreme cases to add a string to trie we have to look through 1 tree of size n, or n trees of size 2. I think it's possible to prove this limit in general with the same logic as in the answer. In other words this approach mixes the trie building and children sorting steps in one.

Comment: I think this answer would be equivalent to sort the array by the first char only, then recursively sort of each subarray. But now the complexity proof seems harder to see.

Comment: @JuanLopes Yeah. But for that you'd also need a sorting algorithm with good properties. For one, it should sort an array with equal elements in omega(n). (Imagine the case where all the strings are different only in the last character)